# Determine a "combined availability" ratio for two servers

Tags: c#, sql-server, report

I need to create a "reliability" report from two servers - server `A` and server `B`.

Both track their uptime - or rather, any case where they are not available. Those records are stored in a SQL Server database table

```
EventID INT  (PK)
Server CHAR(1)   -- 'A' or 'B'
EventStart DATETIME2(3)
EventEnd DATETIME2(3)
```

Sample data:

```
EventID  Server   EventStart                 EventEnd
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  34       A      2014-12-12 14:00:00.000    2014-12-12 15:00:00.000  
  35       A      2014-12-20 10:00:00.000    2014-12-21 03:00:00.000
  36       A      2014-12-27 16:30:00.000    2014-12-27 17:45:00.000
  37       B      2014-12-15 04:00:00.000    2014-12-15 09:35:00.000
  38       B      2014-12-20 20:00:00.000    2014-12-20 21:50:00.000
  39       B      2014-12-27 15:00:00.000    2014-12-27 17:00:00.000
```

These rows of data are loaded into .NET objects using Entity Framework and calculation takes place in C#.

Now given these items, I need to determine (for a given month) how reliable server 'A' and server 'B' where - piece of cake (just sum up the total minutes of downtime for each server and calculate availability).

The tricky part is: I also need a number of minutes that **BOTH** servers were down, during this month - so I can calculate a "combined availability" when at least one of the two servers was accessible.

Of course I can just enumerate all entries for server 'A' and check if there's any entry for server 'B' that overlaps - but that just seems a tad inefficient.

Is there any more sensible approach to do this? I basically have two lists of `Event` objects in C# that have the same fields as the table has columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm:

- Combine the 2 lists
- Order this list by `EventStart`
- Iterate over the sorted list
- Take current and next entry, compare current [`EventStart`, `EventEnd`] with the next `EventStart`
- An overlap would indicate 2 servers were unavailable at the same time

Time complexity: `O(NLog(N)) = O(O(N) + O(NLog(N)) + O(N))`. Space complexity is at least `O(N)`. Where *N* is the count of items in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

For each event, derive a list of minutes (represented by DateTime objects) when the server was down. So for event 34 in your example, this will be 60 DateTime objects.

Put all the downtime minutes (DateTime objects) for a server into a combined list for that server.

Use the linq Union method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the union of the lists from the two servers. Call Count on the result of the Union to find the combined downtime (in minutes).